# Does this implicit div closing contradict the HTML spec?

Tags: html

In the following HTML code, my browser appears to be implicitly closing the div tag, such that cell one appears blue, but cell two does not.

```
<table>
<td><div style="background:blue">cell one</td>
<td>cell two</td>
</div>
</table>
```

Intuitively, this seems like sensible behaviour, but it appears to contradict the HTML spec.

From [12.2.9.6 Unclosed formatting elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#unclosed-formatting-elements)

> nested formatting elements (such as b) get collected and continue to be applied even as the elements they are contained in are closed

From [4.4.15 The div element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-div-element)

> Neither tag is omissible

My reading of this is that the opening of a new `td` tag shouldn't implicitly close the `div` tag, and therefore the styling should continue throughout the table.

Is there something in the spec that I've missed that makes the browsers' behaviour consistent with the spec or is the browser going outside of the formal spec?

*Tested with Chrome, Firefox, IE, Edge*

Comment: validate it - it's invalid for a host of reasons

Comment: Also a div is not a formatting element

Comment: isn't true that "when it is not valid HTML, then the behavior is undefined" -- can be subject to how a browser handles it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No because:

## A `div` is not a formatting element

> The following HTML elements are those that end up in the list of active formatting elements: a, b, big, code, em, font, i, nobr, s, small, strike, strong, tt, and u.

## Tables are special

See [12.2.6.4.15 The "in cell" insertion mode](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#parsing-main-intd) which says:

> Generate implied end tags.